# Laravel AJAX loop

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel

So I am trying to store information form a Form into the database. However, the message I am receiving is a loop the memory_limit grows without stopping, which I sincerely don't know how it may appear.

Initially, I tried to change the `memory_limit` in `php.ini`, because I didn't see what caused the problem. After that, I saw what was happening but since then I am trying to solve it.

How can you solve something that you don't know how it works.

**Route:**

```
Route::resource('/office', 'OfficeController');
```

**Form:**

```
<form id="officeForm">
  <input type="text" name="office_name" placeholder="Има на офис..."><br>
  <input type="text" name="director" placeholder="Управител..."><br>
  <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Адрес..."><br>
  <input type="text" name="phone_number" placeholder="Телефонен номер..."><br>
  <input type="text" name="working_time" placeholder="Работно време...">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="officeSubmit">Добавяне</button>
</form>
```

**AJAX:**

```
$('#officeSubmit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: "/office",
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      office_name: $('input[name=office_name]').val(),
      director: $('input[name=director]').val(),
      address: $('input[name=address]').val(),
      phone_number: $('input[name=phone_number]').val(),
      working_time: $('input[name=working_time]').val()
    },
    success: function() {
      $('input[name=office_name]').val('');
      $('input[name=director]').val('');
      $('input[name=address]').val('');
      $('input[name=phone_number]').val('');
      $('input[name=working_time]').val('');
    }
  });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'office_name' => 'required',
        'director' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'phone_number' => 'required',
        'working_time' => 'required'
    ]);

    var_dump($request);

    $office = new Office();
    $office->office_name = $request->office_name;
    $office->director = $request->director;
    $office->address = $request->address;
    $office->phone_number = $request->phone_number;
    $office->working_time = $request->working_time;
    $office->save();

    return view('home');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ajax code you used

```
method: 'POST',
```

but In your route you declared it resource. try to change it to

```
Router::post('/office', 'OfficeController@store');
```

and also in your form you didn't write

```
<form method="POST" .....>
```

And in the last line on your store method you used

```
return view('home');
```

make that

```
return redirect('/home');
```

Also you can always check you browser's Network tab what code HTTP request returns. Is it 500 or others? 200 is OK.
To get into network tab right click and select inspect elements there are other tabs like Elements, Console, Sources and then Network

Comment: if your problem is solved mark it correct answer or up vote